# why purify tool shows an IPR error on the "throw true" statement?

Tags: c++, multithreading, solaris, rational-purify

while doing an memory checkup with purifier, it is showing an IPR error on the following statement.

```
 throw true;
```

What could be the issue?

```
void Myfunc(char *p_trace_id,char *p_session_id,int &p_roam_flag)
{
   try
   {
      int set_id=0;

      if(0 == set_id)
         throw true;
   }

   catch(bool p_return_value)
   {
      if(!p_return_value)
      {
         g_Log.log(DEBUG, p_trace_id ,"[%s] %s<Line: %d> ", p_session_id ,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);

         p_roam_flag = 0;
      }
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      g_Log.log(DEBUG, p_trace_id ,"[%s] %s<Line: %d> ", p_session_id ,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__);
   }
}
```

As per my analysis, there is issue in [older version](http://www.omniorb-support.com/pipermail/omniorb-list/1999-February/012157.html) of purify. But i am using latest version.

```
Purify V7.0
Solaris V5.0
```

Comment: That code is syntactically incorrect. Did your copy-and-paste key malfunction?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes! Corrected

Comment: The rule 'don't use exceptions for flow control' is much over-cited, way beyond its original purpose (and yes I was there when it started), and there are few live examples of why you should not do so within a method, but this is certainly one of them. There is no reason to use `throw true` here at all, and no reason why the entire `catch (bool ...)` block can't be immediately after the `if` statement. Don't write code like this..

Comment: @EJP I will try to follow this, but i felt like returning the code at beginning of the function after checking pre-condition as something odd.

Comment: How are you compiling the code?  64- or 32-bit?

Comment: @VinothKumar  Try a 32-bit compile and see if you still get the error.  See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PQ92064

Comment: @AndrewHenle But i ran the sample program with try and catch and compiled as 64 bit. But i am not getting any error in purifier.

Comment: Is the sample program the same as the program you posted in your question?

Comment: @AndrewHenle No. But i wrote the same similar code like this.. Do you want to attach the sample code.

Comment: Does the sample code `throw` a `bool`?  If not, it won't really help.  I still think you're running into something like the bug I posted a few days ago, and that's why I wanted you to try both a 32-bit and 64-bit compile with the code that's giving you the error.  You can most likely get a 32-bit compile by adding `-m32` to your compile options.